# Saving Data from a user control WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have two user controls that each contain a numericInput that are added to a Listbox in my MainWindow using an ItemsControl ItemTemplate.  These are both bound to an Ilist property like so, in my ClientRatesViewModel (The one for the MainWindow)
I need to save each value in the Numeric Input in the SaveData method, how can I achieve this?

MainWindow.xaml(Some Code Removed)

```
    <ListBox x:Name="lbPostAwr" ItemsSource="{Binding ClientRatesPostAwrDescription}"
        KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue" Margin="548,23,10,69" av:Grid.Row="1">
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0" Focusable="False">
                    <UserControls:PostAWR />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

ClientRatesViewModel(Some code removed)

```
 public IList<ClientRates> ClientRatesPreAwrValue
    {
        get { return _clientRatePreAwrValue; }
        set
        {
            _clientRatePreAwrValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ClientRatesPreAwrValue");
        }
    }

    public IList<ClientRates> ClientRatesPostAwrValue
    {
        get { return _clientRatePostAwrValue; }
        set
        {
            _clientRatePostAwrValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ClientRatesPostAwrValue");
        }
    }

 private bool SaveData() ///QQQ
    {
        bool isSaved = false;

        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ExtensionMethods.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand("SPHERE", connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    //foreach (var test in this.)
                    //{
                    //    command.Parameters.Add(rate.ClientRatesPreAwr,
                    //}

                    int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    {


                    }
                }
            }
            isSaved = true;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return isSaved;


public IList<ClientRates> ClientRatesPreAwrValue
    {
        get { return _clientRatePreAwrValue; }
        set
        {
            _clientRatePreAwrValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ClientRatesPreAwrValue");
        }
    }

    public IList<ClientRates> ClientRatesPostAwrValue
    {
        get { return _clientRatePostAwrValue; }
        set
        {
            _clientRatePostAwrValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ClientRatesPostAwrValue");
        }
    }
```

My ClientsRates Model looks like this:

```
    private string _clientRatesPreAwrDescription;
    private double _clientRatePreAwrValue;
    private double _clientRatePostAwrValue;
    private string _clientRatePostAwrDescription;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public string ClientRatesPreAwrDescription
    {
        get { return _clientRatesPreAwrDescription; }
        set
        {
            _clientRatesPreAwrDescription = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ClientRatesPreAWR");
        }
    }

    public double ClientRatesPreAwrValue
    {
        get { return _clientRatePreAwrValue; }
        set
        {
            _clientRatePreAwrValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ClientRatesPreAwrValue");
        }
    }

    public double ClientRatesPostAwrValue
    {
        get { return _clientRatePostAwrValue; }
        set
        {
            _clientRatePostAwrValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ClientRatesPostAwrValue");
        }
    }

    public string ClientRatesPostAwrDescription
    {
        get { return _clientRatePostAwrDescription; }
        set
        {
            _clientRatePostAwrDescription = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ClientRatesPostAwr");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You add a Save button, bind it to an ICommand in your view model, and when someone clicks it, you save.  What's the issue?

Comment: I have already done this, however how do I get out every ClientRatePreAwrValue, as this property only holds the last one that was changed.  Thats my issue.

Answer (score 0):

ListBox's ItemsSource has to be bound to a collection, not to the string property (`ClientRatesPostAwrDescription`). Start with the following view:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:ViewModel /> <!--Or set the DataContext in another way-->
</Window.DataContext>
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="lbPostAwr" ItemsSource="{Binding ClientRatesPostAwr}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0" Focusable="False">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Description}" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

and view model(s):

```
public class ClientRateViewModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    Action<object> _execute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) {
        _execute = execute;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter) {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel() {
        ClientRatesPostAwr = new List<ClientRateViewModel>();
        ClientRatesPostAwr.Add(new ClientRateViewModel { Description = "description 1", Value = 1 });
        ClientRatesPostAwr.Add(new ClientRateViewModel { Description = "description 2", Value = 2 });
        SaveCommand = new RelayCommand((o) => {
            MessageBox.Show("Saving: " + string.Join(",", ClientRatesPostAwr.Select(cr => cr.Value.ToString())));
        });
    }

    public IList<ClientRateViewModel> ClientRatesPostAwr { get; private set; }

    public ICommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }
}
```